# Find a random process that is wide-sense stationary (WSS) but not strict-sense stationary etc.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Im studying old exams and came across this one

Question:

a. Find a (discrete time or continuous time) random process that is wide-sense
stationary (WSS) but not strict-sense stationary.

b. Also, is it possible for a strict-sense
stationary random process not to be wide-sense stationary?

Answer:

a. A sequence of uncorrelated random variables with common expected values
and common variances constitute a WSS discrete time process, but is not strict-sense stationary if the random variables are not identically distributed.

b. A seqeunce of independent identically distributed random variables with infinite variances constitute a strict-sense stationary discrete time process that is not WSS.

---

a. Can anyone give a simple example of such a process?

b. Our course litterature says WSS processes are always strict-sense stationary?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. Let $X\sim U(0,2\pi)$ and $Z_n=\sin(nX)$. Then $\{Z_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is weakly stationary, but not strictly stationary.

b. Strictly stationary $L^2$-process (finite second moments) is always weakly stationary.

Comment: So "A seqeunce of independent identically distributed random variables with infinite variances constitute a strict-sense stationary discrete time process that is not WSS."  is not a Strictly stationary $L^2$-process? Im surprised they asked that question in that case because this is a course in basic stochastic processes...nothing advanced.

Comment: @JKnecht Yes. WSS is about expectations and covariances...

Comment: a. Let $X\sim U(0,2\pi)$ and $Z_n=\sin(nX)$. $\{Z_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ Is the autocorrelation function of this zero? =§ I have forgotten the basics...

Comment: @JKnecht: Yes, it's zero.

Comment: Thanks. I had similar problem with the autocorr for $X(n)=cos(nU)$. U uniform $[-\pi,\pi]$ The answer should be $1/2(E(cos(2n+m)U) + E(cos(mU))) = 0 + (1/2)\delta(m)$ but i got $(\frac{1}{2})E(cos(mU)) = (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2m\pi}) [sin (m\pi) - sin(-m\pi)] = 0$ Can you help me out with that one too?

Comment: @JKnecht The variance is 1/2 and $Cov(X(n), X(m))=0$ for $n\ne m$.

Comment: Sigh, im struggling :) $$Cov(X(n),X(m))=E(cos(nU)cos(mU))=(1/2)E(cos((n+m)U)+cos((n-m)U)$$=$$(1/2)(1/(2(m+n)\pi)) [sin(m+n)\pi) - sin(-(m+n)\pi)]$$ + $$(1/2)(1/(2(m-n)\pi)) [sin (m-n)\pi) - sin(-(m-n)\pi)] = 0$$